# Java invoke REST service for x time period for response with periodic interval

Tags: java, rest, scheduledexecutorservice

I have to call a REST endpoint (using Java) to retrieve a response. The configurations are

totalTimeAvailableToCheck = 15 seconds, NoOfAttempts = 3 , intervalInAttempts = 3 seconds.

So consider this an endpoint will be called after every 3 seconds. if I get the desired response then complete the execution else keep on trying after every 3 seconds for next 3 attempts. Total wait time for all this on main thread should not be more than 15 seconds. As rest endpoint could have its own slowness.

Response is just a string(status indicator). So if status is IN PROGRESS keep checking after a interval else if status is DONE/CANCELLED. Returns the status as response.

Edit : Is using a ScheduleEexcutorService for this a better approach ? or any framework that provide this out of box ?

Edit : My first attempts was with `while(true)` but it would have flaw

```
while(attemptCount > noOfAttempts) {
    sleep(3seconds);
    String result = restService.get();
    if(result == in progress) noOfAttempts ++
    else return mapResponse(result);
}
throw timeOutException("timeout")
```

- The flaw with this logic is if rest service call takes long time.

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not being clear. I am thinking if I use ScheduleExecutorService or is there an existing out of the box framework solution I can use

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research a simple approach.

To explain the approach , just call the rest service in a loop in a single thread wait for 15 seconds by using future.get(15 ,TimeUnit.seconds) (as per my requirement future being blocking is not an issue).

```
ExecutorrService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutors();
Future<String> taskStatus = executorService.submit( () -> {
int noOfAttempts = 0;
while(attemptCount > noOfAttempts && !Thread.interrupted()) {
    sleep(intervalInAttempts);
    String result = restService.get();
    if(result == in progress) noOfAttempts ++
    else return result;
}
throw timeOutException("timeout") // or exhaust attempt exception

});

try {
 String status = taskStatus.get(totalTimeAvailableToCheck, TimeUnit.Seconds);
return mapStatus(status);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
throw timeOutException("timeout")
}catch(TimeOutException e) {
taskStatus.cancel(true); // to interrupt the sub tasks
}
```